# How do I reopen a port in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, port

My program bind a port for listening, after it terminates, the port is not available for about a moment and any attempt to open the same port again for listening will fail in that period of time. I need to wait for a while to reopen the port.

I will need to repeatedly bind the port, because I need to retest my server program repeatedly. Is there any linux commands that can release the port prematurely, or any programming code to do the same thing? I code in C++ and uses the gSOAP framework.

Basically I will bind the port using

```
soap_bind(&newsoap, NULL, 13518, 100);
```

which I bind the server to listen on port `13518`.

Ubuntu version: `11.10`

I have tried the same code in Windows, and the port is immediately available after the program terminate. Do I need to do some extra steps in linux to unbind the port before it terminates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind with the [SO_REUSEADDR](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml) socket option to [allow the subsequent bind to succeed](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html). In your case:

```
newsoap.bind_flags |= SO_REUSEADDR;
soap_bind(&newsoap, NULL, 13518, 100);
```

Comment: From what I have read, there seems to be some security issues on using  SO_REUSEADDR, where multiple programs can bind on this same port? Is is recommended to use it, or is it only good for testing purposes?

Comment: Are you actually worried about rogue programs running on that machine stealing your port? If so, what are you doing *now* to stop those programs from starting first? Most likely, it addresses this case too. (You don't need a lock on the window if the door is wide open.)

Comment: Not really, I guess this would be a good solution for my problem then. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the socket.
It is a security feature, that an open port will get locked by the kernel for some time.

I dont know your framework, you have to look at its docs how to close a port with it. I only used the direct kernel calls to use ports.

You might want to read the manpages of `socket` `bind` `listen` and some more of the pages referenced to actually understand how this works.